# A comparison between the verbs (come in / by), (drop in / by), (check in / by) (step in / by) and come over

Tags: verbs

Suppose a lonely mother who has a son who does not give his mother a call for a long time (he doesn't go to his mother home to make sure what is going on and how is his mother's conditions from each viewpoint); then once when son for a reason goes to her home, mother wants to ask (kindly and with a smile on her lips) why you do not visit me at all for a long time; in this scenario do the following sentences mean the same? Which one doesn't sound natural and why? If no what is the difference between them?

> - Why don’t you **come in**?
> - Why don’t you **drop in**?
> - Why don’t you **check in**?
> - Why don’t you **step in**?
> - Why don’t you **come by**?
> - Why don’t you **drop by**?
> - Why don’t you **check by**?
> - Why don’t you **step by**?
> - Why don’t you **come over**?

Answer (score 3):

The thing she wants is a visit. These two specifically imply visiting

> drop in
>
> come over

**come in** and **step in** is used when a person is already at the door

**check in** is used to make contact, perhaps by phone, not really what she wants here.

**come by** **drop by** implies a sort of fleeting, unintentional visit

**step by** **check by** are not phrases I know or use

However any of your phrases sounds a bit peevish or critical. A clever mother praises her son.

> How lovely to see you, so thoughtful of you to come over. It's so nice when you drop in to see me.

Comment: Thank you very much; but would they take an object pronoun?  E.g.  is it possible to say "why don't you drop in to me?) OR (why don't you come over to me?)

Comment: No, no object. You can use a "to ..." qualifier like: Drop in to see me. This needs to be a separate question if you want more detail.

Comment: @A-friend no. You need to say "Why don't you drop in to **see** me?" or "Why don't you come over to **meet** me?" Also, I'm not sure I agree with your interpretation of "come by" and "drop by"... I think they are perfectly fine in this case, if a bit informal. The implication being that there's no need for an appointment.